# Django Sitemap not returning items

Tags: django, django-templates, sitemap

I have a basic sitemap created. However I'm looking to make it more Google compliant.

I have a queryset that works however when I try and access the url.items in my custom template I only get the default 'priority', lastmod etc...

**Sitemaps.py**

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap

from myapp.models import *

class mySitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        articles =
            sync_Binder.objects.select_related() \
            .filter(sync_binder_index__platform_id > = '2') \
            .order_by('sync_binder_index__rank')
        return articles

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.modifieddate
```

**urls.py**

```
sitemaps = {'mysitemap': mySitemap,}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.sitemaps.views',
    (r'^%ssitemap.xml$' % PROJECT_URL, 'sitemap',
        {'sitemaps':sitemaps, 'template_name':'sitemap.html'}),
)
```

**sitemap.html contains the following loop**

```
{% for url in urlset %}
    {{ url.items }}
{% endfor %}
```

...yet I only get the defaults nothing from my articles query set which contains images, headlines etc

Any suggestions?

Thanks
S

Comment: did you try by printing out that articles variable you're returning? what's the output? i'm managin my sitemaps differently, ie i'm not using any sitemap.html template. also, in my sitemap views i'm creating the url directly, so my urls.py is cleaner and has just 2 calls...